# Bootstrap tooltip initialization doesn't work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to implement Bootstrap tooltip that shows full text of articles when i hover my mouse over text. i have two php file. one is `view.php` and the other `fetchdata.php` file. view.php file sends `GET` requests to fetchdata.php and receive Html form data which i want to append to content div. following codes is part of fetchdata.php file codes.

**Fetchdata.php**

```
echo
'<div class ="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
    <div class = "card h-100">
        <a href="'.$link.'" target = "_blank"> <img class = "card-img-top" src = "'.$thumbnail.'" alt= ""> </a>
        <div class ="card-body">
            <h4 class = "card-title">
                <a href ="'.$link.'" target = "_blank">'. $title.'</a>
            </h4>
            <p class ="card - text"> <a href = "#" data-toggle= "tooltip" title = "adsf">'.truncate($summary).'</a> </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>';
```

But it doesn't work well. i searched for that on the internet and many people wrote i should check `jquery` and `bootstrap` initialization sequence and make sure those are correct. So i checked codes and found there is no problem.

**View.php**

```
<head>

    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name ="description" content = "News project">                 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>     
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newslistpage.css">


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {       
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

        if (performance.navigation.type == 1){
            startpages = sessionStorage.getItem('startpages');

            $.get("fetchnews.php",{'p' : startpages},function(data) {
                $('#contentDiv').append(data);  
            });
        }
    }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
....
</body>
```

**Image**

[image]

When i add this test code into body part of `view.php`, it works well. i guess this problem is associated with relation of `php` and `javascript`. So what's wrong with my code and how can i fix them ?

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
```

**Image(after putting above test snippet into codes)**

[image]

Comment: You need to reinitialize the tooltip on the newly appended data. Tooltip works on the existing content since it was initialized on them

Comment: i reinitialized after 'GET' requests. but it made same result .

Comment: You have to reinitialize in the success case, just after appending the new content.

Comment: Oh you solved it thank you! it works properly when i have added initialization codes just after 'append' function which is in $.ajax() success function. but i don't know why it doesn't make right case when i added initialization code after $.ajax() call.

Comment: Subsequent code after the GET request and the Success case are async in nature. So, it success case is executed later while the code after get is executed before.

Comment: oh , i got it !  thank you for your explanation.